# Modify Woocommerce products by columns on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to modify the products inserted in a Wordpress page using shortcodes to be able to view more than one product (2 products) in the same row.
[Shortcodes Wordpress page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gokaf.png)

I have added additional CSS code but I can't get it right.
[Addicional CSS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlWH8.png)

> My website [ebregrow.com](http://ebregrow.com)

This is the code I have tried:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .products {
     width: 50%;
 }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally been able to solve this with this code:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  div.woocommerce ul.products li.product {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}
```